# Two different controls for same bound property?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, asp.net-4.0

I'm trying to create a FormView, which in the EditTemplate can display either a text box or drop down for one of the bound properties, based on some other flag:

```
<asp:FormView 
    id="EmailFormView" 
    runat="server" 
    DefaultMode="Edit" 
    DataSourceID="EmailDataSource"
    OnDataBound="EmailFormView_DataBound" 
>
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="DelayHoursPlaceHolder" runat="server">
            <asp:TextBox CssClass="HoursBox" ID="ShortDelayTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind( "ShortDelay" ) %>' />
        </asp:PlaceHolder>
        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="DelayDropdownPlaceHolder" runat="server">
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ShortDelay" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind( "ShortDelay" ) %>'  
                DataValueField="Value" DataTextField="Text" DataSourceID="DropDownDataSource" />
        </asp:PlaceHolder>
    </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:FormView>
```

This works with this code:

```
protected void EmailFormView_DataBound( object sender, EventArgs e ) {
    var email = EmailObj;

    if (email.EmailType == EmailType.Type1) {
        EmailFormView.Row.FindControl("DelayHoursPlaceHolder").Visible = false;
        EmailFormView.Row.FindControl("DelayDropdownPlaceHolder").Visible = true;
    }
    else {
        EmailFormView.Row.FindControl("DelayHoursPlaceHolder").Visible = true;
        EmailFormView.Row.FindControl("DelayDropdownPlaceHolder").Visible = false;
        EmailFormView.Row.FindControl("DelayDropdownPlaceHolder").Controls.Clear();
    }
}
```

This works fine to show and hide the appropriate controls, but the problem is that when the page is posted back, the value is being lost.

Any ideas on how to get this working?

Comment: Show the code where you're doing the databinding to the `FormView`.  You need to make sure that it is not rebinding after the postback.  That is, it is wrapped in an `if (!IsPostBack) { }`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure in your `Page_Load` event, that you only bind the drop down list when the page is first loaded, like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!PostBack)
    {
        // Bind drop down list here
    }
}
```